# RichFaces rich:tree nodeSelectListener not being listened to

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have a `rich:tree` component used like so:

```
                    <rich:tree switchType="client" value="#{MyBacking.logTree}"
                    reRender="selectedLog" var="item" nodeFace="#{item.type}"
                    nodeSelectListener="#{MyBacking.processLogSelection}"
                    style="width: 50px;">
                    <rich:treeNode type="folder"
                        icon="/img/logListFolderIconClosed.png"
                        iconLeaf="/img/logListFolderIconOpen.png">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                    </rich:treeNode>
                    <rich:treeNode type="log" iconLeaf="/img/logFileIcon.png"
                        icon="/img/logFileIcon.png">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                    </rich:treeNode>
                </rich:tree>
```

and my MyBacking processLogSelection() method is:

```
    public void processLogSelection(NodeSelectedEvent event) {
    logger.info("In processLogSelection");
    HtmlTree tree = (HtmlTree) event.getComponent();
    nodeTitle = (String) tree.getRowData();
    selectedNodeChildren.clear();
    TreeNode currentNode = tree.getModelTreeNode(tree.getRowKey());
    if (currentNode.isLeaf()){
        selectedNodeChildren.add((String)currentNode.getData());
    } else {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Object, TreeNode>> it = currentNode.getChildren();
        while (it != null && it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Object, TreeNode> entry = it.next();
            selectedNodeChildren.add(entry.getValue().getData().toString()); 
            logger.info("selected node: " + entry.getValue().getData().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

But when the page renders the tree (fine) clicking on a node highlights the node but nothing is logged from either of the bean logger calls - the method is just not being called.  Any help answering why this might be would be greatly appreciated.
Mark

**EDIT** Added suggested tags/simplified bean method - still doesn't appear to get response from the bean as far as logs go:

```
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" border="0" width="100%" rowClasses="tt">
            <rich:panel styleClass="panelLogTree" header="Log Select">
                <h:form>
                    <rich:tree switchType="client" value="#{MyBacking.logTree}"
                        var="item" nodeFace="#{item.type}" reRender="selectedLog"
                        nodeSelectListener="#{MyBacking.processLogSelection}"
                        ajaxSubmitSelection="true" style="width: 50px;">
                        <rich:treeNode type="folder"
                            icon="/img/logListFolderIconClosed.png"
                            iconLeaf="/img/logListFolderIconOpen.png">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                        </rich:treeNode>
                        <rich:treeNode type="log" iconLeaf="/img/logFileIcon.png"
                            icon="/img/logFileIcon.png">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                        </rich:treeNode>
                    </rich:tree>
                </h:form>
            </rich:panel>

            <rich:panel styleClass="panelLogOutput" header="Log Content">
                <h:outputText escape="false"
                    value="Log content: #{MyBacking.nodeTitle}" id="selectedLog" />
            </rich:panel>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </rich:tab>
```

Note the end `rich:tab` as this tree is rendering in a tab, from an included jsp file.  My backing bean method is also now:

```
    public void processLogSelection(NodeSelectedEvent event) {
    logger.info("In processLogSelection");
}
```

**FURTHER EDIT**
Interestingly, I thought I'd rip back to a basic working model.  I took the code from the [RichFaces Demo Page](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/tree.jsf?tab=model&cid=3835901).  I modified the faces-config.xml to include the `SimpleTreeData` bean.  I had trouble getting the bean code which reads the data file in (`simple-tree-data.properties`) so I used a `FileReader` instead.  This built ok, and I got a modified index.jsp jsf page to list the simple tree example as on the demo page, except clicking on a list item didn't report the selected `nodeTitle` to the specified place (same problem).

I can see this either as the same problem reported above or the fact that the `loadTree` method in the `SimpleTreeData.java` bean has been changed.  In the change, I removed the following lines and changed extraneous code as appropriate:

```
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    InputStream dataStream = externalContext.getResourceAsStream(DATA_PATH);
```

As mentioned earlier, I used a `FileReader` but does anyone think this problem could be related to me removing these 3 lines?  As also listed above, my `processLogSelection` method doesn't use `getCurrentInstance` but I'm not sure it needs to if `ajaxSubmitSelection="true"` is listed in the JSF.

Stumped.

Comment: Have you tried ajaxSubmitSelection="true" as an attribute of rich:tree? Ah, and make sure the rich:tree is surrounded by a form.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both with no success. I'll experiment a bit more and report back.

Comment: `ajaxSubmitSelection="true"` should work (it works here) - check your logs for why it isn't.

Comment: Should it matter that the `rich:tree` is part of an `a4j:include`d page?

Comment: I tried nesting your above code in tabpanel and it still works. Just kidding, but are you sure your logging works:)

Comment: Yep. As I'm going mad, I put `System.out.println ("*** in processLogSelection ***");` into my bean method and it's still dead. When you tested it, are you `a4j:include` ing the `rich:tree` tag? I'm thinking it might be that given that I can't think of anything else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this was to install a facelets jar. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335490/richfaces-richpanelmenu-stops-working-when-a4jincluded/2374298#2374298).  It affected other problems of mine, unsurprisingly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [this facelets template](http://pastie.org/841905) and this [sample java backing bean](http://pastie.org/841906) and the method was called. I assumed you use Seam but maybe I am wrong:) A little while ago there were some complaints: [seam forum](http://seamframework.org/Community/DynamicTreeAndNodeSelectListener). What version of Richfaces are you using and what browser? If you use also Seam, please tell its version.

Comment: I don't use seam. I'm using RF3.3.2 SR1. I read the Seam complaints before but as I'm not using Seam it was of limited use.  I'm using Firefox v3.5.8 to test.